# Differnce betwen Array in Jquery and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if Array defined in jquery is somehow different from array defined in javascript?
Like type of "elements they can store" and more.......

Comment: jQuery is JavaScript, so Array is the same as far as I know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

jQuery is a library for JavaScript, not a different programming language. It does not provide a custom array type.

Comment: Ahh...Thanks!! I got it now, Actually the book i was reading is a "Bit messy " in it's language. Hence confusion occurred.

Comment: Do i need to delete this question ??